# Difference between Global Data Services and a DDBMS (Distributed Database Management System) with Oracle12c

Tags: oracle12c

I have to make a documentation about distributed databases with Oracle 12c. Could you help me understand if the new service GDS (Global Data Services) is the new DDBMS (distributed database management system) or is a completely different thing? What are the differences between them? I have understood that they do quite the same thing.

Comment: What have you found online so far?

Comment: I found that GDS provides a single system image to manage database workload amongst replicated databases; With GDS, a set of replicated databases appear to the applications as single data source.
I understand quite the same thing from a DDBMS: a centralized application that manages a distributed database as if it were all stored on the same computer. The DDBMS synchronizes all the data periodically, and in cases where multiple users must access the same data, ensures that updates and deletes performed on the data at one location will be automatically reflected in the data stored elsewhere.

Comment: I'm having doubts because I can not find any clear relationship between them